# "Pharma" UX Model?

Tags: forms, login, workflow, learning, mental-models

**Is there any known "Pharma" like UX examples or flows out there in the digital world?**

Example:  Doctor recommends a drug to a patient, hands off prescription to receptionist to make a copy. Receptionist hands copy to patient.  Patient goes to pharmacy and hands off prescription to get it filled. patient receives the drug.

I am searching for that type of an example, only this deals all on an "online" process.

The design I am currently working on requires a "certifier" (Could be doctor, phycologist, sppecial ed teacher, etc..) type role to be able to log into our system and "prescribe" or "sign off"(may be a form to fill out for us) on a user (person with a print/learning disability) that they recommend for our our content (Audiobooks).  That user would then have access to our content w=once registering because they had a "certifier" sign off on them using it.

Comment: Lots of systems have approval processes. Not saying they are good UX, but check SharePoint, a lot of CMS products, HR systems, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as an "Approval" process, you may have better luck researching that term.

However, I've done this on multiple systems in multiple industries. My suggestions are to have the following:

- Home page with quick access to "My pending approvals" and "Create prescription" (substitute with whatever is relevant)
- Concise notification area that they can quickly see what needs their attention

Since I'm assuming the approval/prescription process is the primary role of the system, try to encapsulate 80% of this within 2-3 steps after logging in.

Answer (score 2):

The first pattern that comes to mind is something like the forget password flow.

User fills out and submits form requesting "certification".

```
(You forget password but know your information, enter email and request new one)
```

Certifier receives request, authorizes. An email is sent to user with an account specific link with access to perscribed content.

```
(you get an email  with link to a special part of the site where your password can be reset)
```

User enters site through that link and sets up account on the content area.

```
(You reset password and gain access to account)
```

Acess to the certified content is restricted unless they have an account or this specially generated link.

There are slight differences of course. The password reset is automated. I imagine you want an actual review of the submission.

Hope this helps.